# How to merge data frames on floats?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can you merge two dataframes on a float column? Below is a reproducible example. I'm sure it has to do with the two float columns not being equal but would like an explanation and possibly a more elegant solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

left = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(10, 11, .05)})
right = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(10,11,.1), 'b': np.random.random_sample((10,))})
```

Trying to merge these I get:

```
pd.merge(left, right, how='left', on='a')

Out[182]: 
        a         b
0   10.00  0.913439
1   10.05       NaN
2   10.10       NaN
3   10.15       NaN
4   10.20       NaN
5   10.25       NaN
6   10.30       NaN
7   10.35       NaN
8   10.40       NaN
9   10.45       NaN
10  10.50       NaN
11  10.55       NaN
12  10.60       NaN
13  10.65       NaN
14  10.70       NaN
15  10.75       NaN
16  10.80       NaN
17  10.85       NaN
18  10.90       NaN
19  10.95       NaN
```

But, if I re-format the 'a' column I get the desired result:

```
left.a = left.a.map(lambda x : format(x,'.2f'))
right.a = right.a.map(lambda x : format(x,'.2f'))

pd.merge(left, right, how='left', on='a')

Out[184]: 
        a         b
0   10.00  0.913439
1   10.05       NaN
2   10.10  0.468474
3   10.15       NaN
4   10.20  0.969810
5   10.25       NaN
6   10.30  0.304893
7   10.35       NaN
8   10.40  0.375873
9   10.45       NaN
10  10.50  0.639368
11  10.55       NaN
12  10.60  0.723442
13  10.65       NaN
14  10.70  0.916725
15  10.75       NaN
16  10.80  0.366827
17  10.85       NaN
18  10.90  0.664318
19  10.95       NaN
```

I'm wondering if someone can explain why this happens and if there is an easier solution than my map, format lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pd.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
pd.merge_asof(left, right, on='a', tolerance = 0.01)
```

It will do a left merge, and you can set a tolerance value.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!